# How do I recover from a WebSocket client computer going to sleep or app going to background (Safari on iPad)

Tags: javascript, ipad, websocket, socket.io

I have browser client Javascript which opens a WebSocket (using socket.io) to request a long-running process start, and then gets a callback when the process is done.  When I get the callback, I update the web page to let the user know the process has completed.

This works ok, except on my iPad when I switch to another app and then come back (it never gets the callback, because I guess the app is not online at the time).  I'm assuming the same thing will happen on a laptop or other computer that sleeps while waiting for the callback.

Is there a standard way (or any way) to deal with this scenario?  Thanks.

For reference, if you want to see the problem page, it is at http://amigen.perfectapi.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider in this scenario:

**Detect the app going off/on line**

See: [`online`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/online_event) and [`offline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/offline_event) events

When your app detects the `online` event after the computer wakes up you can get any information that you've missed.

For older web browsers you'll need to do this in a cleverer way. At [Pusher](http://pusher.com) we've added a ping - pong check between the client and server. If the client doesn't receive a ping within a certain amount of time it knows there's a connection problem. If the server sends a ping and doesn't get a pong back with a certain time it knows there's a problem.

A ping pong mechanism is [defined in the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/network.html#ping-and-pong-frames) but a way of sending a ping or pong hasn't been defined on the WebSocket API as yet.

**Fetching missed information**

Most realtime servers only deliver messages to connected to clients. If a client isn't connected, maybe due to temporary network disturbance or their computer has been asleep for a while, then those clients will miss the message.

Some frameworks do provide access to messages through a history/cache. For those that don't you'll need to detect the problem (as above) and then fetch any missed messages. A good way to do this is by providing a timestamp or sequence ID with each messages so you can make a call to your web server to say "give me all messages since X".

Comment: Just for the record, Socket.IO also implements a 'ping pong', called a heartbeat. This will check if the connection is still active or not. The heartbeat (ping) interval can be configured.

Comment: @alessioalex +1 for comment. Useful info. Thanks.