# Patterns for handling missed push events? E.g. chat messages sent while offline or in sleep mode

Tags: angularjs, websocket, pusher

I'm writing an app that uses WebSockets via [Pusher](http://pusher.com). This is a Ruby on Rails + AngularJS app but this should apply to any stack, really.

I just realized my app doesn't handle missed push events, and I'm interested to hear what some established patterns for this are.

My app isn't a chat, but let's pretend it is.

- When the page loads, it gets the last 100 chat messages from the DB and shows them.
- Whenever a new chat message comes in, the server pushes the new message to the clients via Pusher/WebSockets.
- But! If a client is offline or in sleep mode when a push comes in, they can miss messages.

What's a good pattern for handling that?

I have some vague ideas around detecting the client "waking up" and either forcing a full page reload or requesting events since a certain timestamp or since a certain event, but then I'm not sure what would be a good way of determining "waking up" without adding polling into the mix. Maybe using Pusher's [client presence](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels) or [connection states](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#connection-states) features, detecting when a user just (re-)connected?

I haven't been able to find a way of getting a history of events from Pusher, so I guess I would have to store those myself, then send them back to that client only.

Comment: Kind of related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853048/how-do-i-recover-from-a-websocket-client-computer-going-to-sleep-or-app-going-to/8881818#8881818

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that when the page loads, your client gets the last 100 messages from the database. From that, I understand that you, in addition to pushing out the messages via Pusher, keep track of all messages in your database.

So when your client comes online, it should check the same endpoint it would normally check when visiting the page for the first time. You can then compare the returned set against the messages you have cached on the client and see if you missed anything.

I'm not too familiar with the Pusher API, but it seems to me that you can listen for the `unavailable` or `disconnected` events. So you would just set a flag when you see those events, wait for your connection to be reestablished and then you pull the history from the server again and compare against the local cache.

Comment: The safest time to get older messages is when the connection status changes to `connected`. This is the case on both initial load and upon reconnection (`connected`). See the connection states doc http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#connection-states

Comment: It actually doesn't check an endpoint as such – the server renders JSON data into some inline JavaScript so we have data without waiting for an additional request. But I could of course add such an endpoint. I like the simplicity of just getting the last 100 messages again and figuring out which you've seen. I'll keep that option in mind. Thank you! And you as well, @leggetter. Knowing *when* to check for updates was more of a mystery to me than *how* to get them :)